# Can't load img use (backgroud-image:url(""))from a style sheet

Tags: css

my project's resources ：

```
    |--static
    |----img
    |------foo.jpg
    |----css
    |------style.css
    |--templates
    |----index.html
```

i want load **foo.jpg** from img directory.in index.html , it **works** in follows :

```
    .foo{
        background-image:url("../../img/foo.png")
    }
```

but it **not working** anymore when i move it into the style.css like :

```
    .foo{
        background-image:url("../img/foo.png")
    }
```

actually,i had revised the relative path to foo.img,
how can i correctly load this image ?

Answer (score 0):

- make sure that which you are using as a image type, once you using  `background-image:url("../img/foo.png")` as a `PNG` but in your folder its a `JPG` file.